# Django database settings for production server

Tags: database, django, production

I have a problem with Django database configuration with 'postgresql_psycopg2'
If I give any arbitrary name to my database like below,

```
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': 'xyz',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            'USER': 'postgres',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
            'PASSWORD': '${my_password}',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
            'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
            'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
            'OPTIONS': {
                "autocommit": True,
            }
        }
    }
> 

OperationalError at /

FATAL:  database "xyz" does not exist
```

I surf a lot and findout same that with SQLite we have to specify absolute path to our database; with PostGRE likewise above.

I would like to know:
1) Why I am getting error message with above specification and
2) How I use my database which i am using with Development server lay out in filesystem (windows).

Comment: You could use some #2 from http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/top-15-best-practices-for-writing-super-readable-code/ because it really hard to read those settings

Comment: 1) is xyz an existing postgresql database ? 2) using a sqlite database for production environments is NOT recommended!

Comment: You're using the Django 1.2+ multi-database adaptor syntax, which means you should (I think) be explicitly referring to your postgresql adaptor: "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2 not just "postgresql_psycopg2".  Also, do you definitely have `psycopg2` installed?

Comment: hello JackLeo, I would like to say that your reply is not concerned with this post at all.

Comment: hello Tommaso,(1) 'xyz' is not existing database in PostGreSQL (2) I am not using SQLite for Production server. I would like to state, with Development server I am using my database which has been lay out in my filesystem(windows) say,c:\${app_name}\data.db which indeed I would like to use it Production server but when I passed the same with NAME parameter like; 'NAME': 'c:\${app_name}\data.db', it intimate me error message FATAL:  database "C:/${app_name}/data.db" does not exist which is also indeed right since the particular not being existed with PostGreSGL.

Comment: hello stevejalim, I am using Django 1.2.4; I tried your suggestion 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2' but having the same effect. Anyway, could you please explain me below aspects like;
-1 How you come to know that I am using 'multi-database adaptor syntax' (even I am not being aware with it
-2 What is 'single-database adaptor syntax' ?
-3 And last what is 'database adaptor' ?; I tried to ggogle it but seems it very difficult to interpret  since I am from Mobile domain and incidentally have to working on web application

Comment: you should'nt put your name in the question :P

Answer (score 0):

> I surf a lot and findout same that
>   with SQLite we have to specify
>   absolute path to our database; with
>   PostGRE likewise above.

Just to be clear (your wording isn't) with postgresql there is no absolute path, it's just the name of the database.

1: The error message is pretty clear, database xyz does not exist.

Go to the dbshell (`python manage.py dbshell`) and type in `\l`. If database `xyz` isn't in there, type in `create database xyz`, exit the postgres shell and try syncdb again.

2: For your development server, I recommend using sqlite3 for its ease of use.

`sqlite` is included in python 2.5+, so no extra settings are required. Simply set your `ENGINE` to `sqlite3`, specify an absolute path to where you want the database saved, and `python manage.py syncdb`

Comment: Hello Yuji,
I am also stated the same that with PostGreSQL we have just database name like, ${database_name}
${project_name}> manage.py dbshell
Giving the same error message,
psql: FATAL:  database "xyz" does not exist

I had 2 ways to check your suggestion,
1- Either I would change database NAAE in settings.py like,
'NAME': 'postgres', //since I found it’s a default database created while PostGre installation

but after that when I checked for database named 'xyz' which obviously would not be there; and later created it with command (suggested by you only)
create database xyz #Plz Cont...#

Comment: but then again it was listing there!

2- When I try with below command in order to go with dbsheell,
psql.exe"  -h localhost -p 5432 postgres "postgres"

having the same result; database is not creating.

Eventually I gone through 'pgAdmin3.exe' and created a database which would be sync later with,
manage.py syncdb

But look it is not serving which I would be needed.
Let me explain first about the scenario. I have given a django project developed with someone else.
Since, I am having just Development server database file which lay out in filesystem(windows) say,
C:\${project_name}\data.db#PC#

Comment: And would be the same corresponding file for Production server is with Developer, in his PostGre installation directory.

But I didn't get that one.

Now I must use C:\${project_name}\data.db
But don't know how?


Amit.